# Assigning package name after changing the folder structure

Tags: struts2

In My struts2 project, I recently changed the folder structure,
 The following image shows the new folder structure.

[image: New folder Structure]

So as a consequence i need to change the package name in Struts.xml.
I am a newbie to struts 2.So please suggest me the package name that suits for the above
folder structure. I have tried out 
 in the below format. But it did not work.

[image]

In the above snippet,i set the package name as seasar.action Because i am having all of my
 action classes in it.

Comment: what did not worked out for you? more over package structure is a logical separation.

Comment: obviously,after changing the folder structure, we need to give the source from where the action class will be loaded. In my case, I don't know what package name to give in the name attribute of package tag..! So whenever i try to execute my project.. It is showing "page cannot found..!"

Comment: i am not getting your inputs properly.i told you these are logical separations and have nothing to do with the action search.All you have to make sure that your configuration for actions are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package names are arbitrary; you can name it whatever you want.

Packages should be named something meaningful in the context of the app. One reason for multiple packages is to allow package-level configuration, like interceptor stacks, default result types, etc.

For example, a package may be used to provide "secured" access: its default interceptor stack might include a "login required"-type interceptor. One package might encapsulate an app's REST API and set the default result type to "json". Packages are just one mechanism to aggregate functionality.

Ultimately, package naming is application-specific, invisible to the end-user, and provided as a mean for developers to logically group arbitrary functionality, purpose, or intent.